# Unity: create mesh from a 2D line

Tags: unity-game-engine, line, mesh, renderer, vertices

I am a beginner with vertice and mesh. 
I want to get a user drawing, it will be a line/spline in one surface (2D) (X,Z) . 
*I think I could do this with a line renderer, maybe.*

From this line, (i see with line render, i have an array with point) generate a mesh in one direction (for example 2 axis).
And then add a collider and texture to this mesh.

At the end it will be like a maze create by the user and then he could move in.

Have you some idea of the different step I have to do ?

Comment: search for brackeys channel on YouTube. 2 of his last videos were about mesh generation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJEpeUH1EMg

Comment: What I want to do and don't know how to do is :

draw a line with mouse : this is normally ok with line renderer

get all this point that represent the line : I saw the array in the inspector, if think it should be lineRenderer.GetPosition fonction

create a mesh from these points in one direction ( if the lien was in (x,y) plane, i want to create an mesh along z axis) : don't know how to do this

add a collider to this mesh : don't know how to do this

Comment: do it with line renderer. there is a manual way but its way more involved